# How can I wrap the Children of a Parent component in a HOC and render them in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Let me start by saying that this example is very simple and can be solved with React.cloneElement. But I want more freedom and the project will be more complex, so I'd like to find a solution.
I would also like to understand what I'm missing :/

I want to be able to augment the children of a Parent component with props and methods (hence the HOC). It would start from here:

```
<Parent>
  <aChild />
  <anotherChild />
  <yetAnotherChild />
</Parent>
```

And this is the Parent component (called Sequence in my project), so far:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const withNotification = handler => Component => props => (
  <Component onAnimationEnd={handler} {...props} />
);

class Sequence extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pointer: 0,
    };

    this.notifyAnimationEnd = this.notifyAnimationEnd.bind(this);

    this.Children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, Child =>
      withNotification(this.notifyAnimationEnd)(Child)
    );
  }

  notifyAnimationEnd() {
    // do stuff
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.Children.map((Child, i) => {
          if (i <= this.state.pointer) return <Child />;
          return <div>nope</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sequence;
```

I get the following error:

[image: React Error]

You can play with the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6w1n5wor9w

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will not solve your problem but maybe gives a hint why this is not possible. At first I was surprised why your code does not work, even though I'm not an experienced React developer it seems ok map `this.props.children` through with `React.Children.map` and return the desired Component with your HOC. But it did not work.

I tried to debug it a little bit and [did some search](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2982). I've learned `props.children` **actually contains the elements itself not the instances of components.** Even, `React.Children.map` does not have any effect on this.

Here is a working snippet proves that your problem is not related with the HOC. I've used an array of components instead of mapping through `props.children`.

```js
class Line1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.props.onAnimationEnd, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Line 1</div>;
  }
}

class Line2 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.props.onAnimationEnd, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Line 2</div>;
  }
}

class Line3 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.props.onAnimationEnd, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Line 3</div>;
  }
}


const withNotification = handler => Component => props => (
  <Component onAnimationEnd={handler} {...props} />
);

class Sequence extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pointer: 0
    };

    this.notifyAnimationEnd = this.notifyAnimationEnd.bind(this);

    this.Arr = [ Line1, Line2, Line3 ];
    this.Children = this.Arr.map(Child =>
      withNotification(this.notifyAnimationEnd)(Child)
    );
  }

  notifyAnimationEnd() {
    this.next();
  }

  next() {
    // Clearly, render the next element only if there is, a next element
    if (this.state.pointer >= this.Arr.length - 1) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ pointer: this.state.pointer + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.Children.map((Child, i) => {
          if (i <= this.state.pointer) return <Child />;
          return <div>nope</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Sequence />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting and the discussion you linked enlighting. It's good to know it at least! I went on and had a look at react-transition-group code which does exactly what I'm trying to replicate here, and found out that in fact they use React.cloneElement: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/c3b7708a536a7625770c5131137ba8ec3aea82a2/src/utils/ChildMapping.js#L88

Comment: Good catch. Then, it is certain that `cloneElement` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `<Child />` instead of `Child` in Sequence.js render method. Here is my edited copy - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zp7jq09px)